# Performance testing on Navision deployment

Tags: performance-testing, navision

Im trying to figure out if there is a way to do good performance testing on a Navision deployment. Our customer uses a customized verison of Navision so we need to test the performance to ensure we dont destroy anything.
The customer hosts the Navision server themself but we do the Development and the deployment when we have changes.
We need to be able to meassure different kinds of transactions like searching for a customer or posting an invoice.
Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, most of them would be running on the DB side. You can for example examine the customer table index by using: 
    < dbcc showcontig('XXXX$Customer','$1') >

Examine the "Logical Scan Fragmentaion" and the "Scan Density". IF the "Logical Scan Fragmentaion" lower than 10 % we can say it perfect. also if the "Scan Density" is more than 90% we can also say its really good.

There are 3 different layers in Navision (Assuming you are using the Classic clients):

```
1- Interface Layer ---- > Page or Form
2- Logic           ---- > were calculation are made
3- Data layer      ---- > Date Base
```

The question is which layer you want to examine? and you have to keep in mind that bad coding also coz massive performance issues!
I would recommend you take a look also at all customized objects. Its a lot of work, there are some specialties in this field which are really experience in testing Navision performance. But they cos a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

For a standard NAV workflow cases you can use SQL Profiler and internal NAV tools like "Client Monitor", "Code Coverage" depending on the version you have and depending on a depth level you need to analyze.

Keys/Indexes are another major topic for optimization: here you should refer to SQL Index usage statistics and other data from SQL and work with it together wiith code/business workflows. You can refer to https://mibuso.com/ and https://dynamicsuser.net/ and search for forums and downloads sections for more related information.